# how to combine two dictionary values as a key and value pair in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

```
let arra = ["abc","def","abc","def"]
let arra2 = ["addr1","addr2","addr1","addr2"]
```

Expected Output

```
dic = ["abc":"addr1","addr1" , def: "addr2","addr2"]
```

Comment: The output dictionary you've provided is malformed. Did you mean `dic = ["abc": "addr1", "def": "addr2"]`?

Comment: Your "expected output" is some weird (invalid) syntax that's half dictionary and half array.  Can you clarify what you meant exactly?

Comment: Please edit your questions and fix the expected output. You probably meant `["abc":["addr1","addr1"],"def": ["addr2","addr2"]]`

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4's new Dictionary initializer lets you do that kind of thing easily:

```
let arra = ["abc","def","abc","def"]
let arra2 = ["addr1","addr2","addr1","addr2"]

let dict = [String:[String]](zip(arra,arra2.map{[$0]}),uniquingKeysWith:+)

print(dict) // ["abc": ["addr1", "addr1"], "def": ["addr2", "addr2"]]
```

[EDIT] Swift 3 equivalent :

```
var dict : [String:[String]] = [:]
zip(arra,arra2.map{[$0]}).forEach{ dict[$0] = (dict[$0] ?? []) + $1 }
```

Comment: Nice. The trick is mapping each array element into a single element array.

Comment: can u do in swift 3?

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip(_:_:)` and `reduce(_:_:)`:

```
let array1 = ["abc", "def", "abc", "def"]
let array2 = ["addr1", "addr2", "addr1", "addr2"]

let dictionary = zip(array1, array2).reduce([String: String]()) {
  var dictionary = $0

  dictionary[$1.0] = $1.1

  return dictionary
}

print(dictionary) // ["abc": "addr1", "def": "addr2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be easier way but in general:

```
import UIKit

let keyArray = ["abc","def","abc","def"]
let valueArray = ["addr1","addr2","addr1","addr2"]

let setFromKeyArray = Set(keyArray)

var finalDict = [String: [String]]()
for index in 0..<keyArray.count {
    if let _ = finalDict[keyArray[index]] {
        finalDict[keyArray[index]]!.append(valueArray[index])
    } else {
        finalDict[keyArray[index]] = [valueArray[index]]
    }
}

print(finalDict)
// output: ["abc": ["addr1", "addr1"], "def": ["addr2", "addr2"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best of [Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8461625/dennis-vennink) and [Kristijan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1829206/kristijan-delivuk) and [Alain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5237560/alain-t).

```
let arra = ["abc", "def", "abc", "def"]
let arra2 = ["addr1", "addr2", "addr1", "addr2"]

let dict = zip(arra, arra2).reduce([String:[String]]()){
    var d = $0
    d[$1.0] = ($0[$1.0] ?? []) + [$1.1]
    return d
}

print(dict) // ["def": ["addr2", "addr2"], "abc": ["addr1", "addr1"]]
```

Remember dictionary is unordered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below :

```
let arra = ["abc","def","abc","def"]
let arra2 = ["addr1","addr2","addr1","addr2"]

var dictionary: [String: String] = [:]
dictionary.merge(zip(arra, arra2)) { (old, new) -> String in
    return "\(old), \(new)"
}

print(dictionary)
```

Output :

```
["abc": "addr1, addr1", "def": "addr2, addr2"]
```

Comment: .merge can't get  in swift 3